# why changing pointer to array name changes result?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, sizeof, implicit-conversion

In the below code if I change `int (*p)[R][C];` to `int p[R][C];` result change from 800 to 80. why does this happens as i understand in `int p[R][C];` array name `p` is also a pointer like `*p` in`int (*p)[R][C];`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define R 10
#define C 20

int main()
{
   int (*p)[R][C];
   printf("%d",  sizeof(*p));
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

PS:- is `*p` in`int (*p)[R][C];` acting as a pointer to another pointer which is actually pointing to the array?

Comment: the first creates an array of pointers not an array of ints.

Comment: @johnelemans the first is a pointer to a multidimensional integer array not array of pointers!

Comment: `printf("%d",  sizeof(*p));` is wrong.  `sizeof()` returns `size_t`, and the correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
int (*p)[R][C];
```

declares a pointer to an array having the type `int[R][C]`. The result of the expression `sizeof( int[R][C] )` is equal to `R * C * sizeof( int )`.

The expression `*p` has the type `int[R][C]`. So `sizeof( *p )` is equivalent to `sizeof( int[R][C]` ).

As for this declaration

```
int p[R][C];
```

then the array designator p in the expression `*p` is converted to pointer to its first element and dereferencing the pointer you will get the first element of the array that has the type `int[C]`.

So for the first declaration of the variable `p` as a pointer `sizeof( *o )` is equal to `sizeof( int[R][C]`.

For the second declaration of the variable `p` as a two-dimensional array `sizeof( *p )` is equal to `sizeof( int[C] )`.

Using the first declaration of p as a pointer you could get the same result as for p declared as an array if you wrote

```
sizeof( **p )
```

That is dereferencing the pointer the first time you get an object of the type that is used in the second declaration to declare the variable p as an array.

Pay attention to that this call

```
printf("%d",  sizeof(*p));
```

has undefined behavior because there is used a wrong conversion format. You have to write

```
printf("%zu",  sizeof(*p));
```

Comment: Does that means `*p` in `int (*p)[R][C];` acting as a pointer to another pointer which is actually pointing to the array?

Comment: @gisire It is a pointer to an object of the array type int[R][C].

Comment: As I think  `*p` in `int (*p)[R][C];` is like we are dereferencing `p` one time so now we are actually at `p[0]` which is the first element in `array p`

Comment: @gisire This int (*p)[R][C]; is a declaration of a pointer. The record *p used in expressions yields the pointed object that is an object of the type int[R][C]. It is the same as if you have a declaration like int *p; then expression *p yields an object of the type int.

Comment: @4386427 It is a valid statement. The pointer p is defined like int ( *p )[R][C];

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates! This question is about what is the difference between a pointer and array in C.

Comment: @Kaz No, the question is not about this. It is about the sizeof operator and the dereferencing operator.